# Trying to restrict ssh access to domain groups

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, redhat, authentication

Centos 7 joined to 2012 R2 AD domain

Joined to AD domain with realm join and now I can ssh in as any domain user (**ssh server -l domusr@lab.local**)

I want to only allow certain domain groups to ssh in so I added this to the bottom of /etc/ssh/ssh_config:

(**serveradmins** is an AD security group)

```
AllowGroups serveradmins
DenyUsers *
```

I rebooted.

But any domain user can still login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you edited is the ssh **client** configuration. You want sshd_config.

Comment: whoops that was an obvious mistake. I now have another problem though (maybe I should create another question for this). I specified the AD group to allow, but its not allowing users in that group to login. you shouldn't have to specify the domain name in the group right?

Comment: Depends on how you have things set up. Should be easy enough to try both ways, no?